# UBER reminder API 403 ERROR

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to make call to uber reminder API POST /v1.2/reminders

with headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Authorization: Token `O8Qh38yDlHKraXIIPO0ay-3CRLVgZY5Rtk5ZCNoB`

and JSON data:

```
{
"reminder_time": 1429294463,
"phone_number": "+10000000000",
"event": {
    "time": 1429294463  ,
    "name": "Frisbee with friends",
    "location": "Dolores Park",
    "address": "532-564 Dolores St, San Francisco, CA 94114, USA",
    "product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d"
    }
}
```

I also added my IP address in white list IP addresses in UBER developer portal but still getting 403 error.

Comment: Hello-- please see the StackOverflow Uber-api post right before your post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248996/uber-ride-reminder-api-responding-403-forbidden-response

"The reminders API is now only available after whitelisting. Can you reach out via the developer dashboard or dm @uberdevelopers?"

Comment: thanks for reply.I want to ask for reminder api ,I need to request full access of which specific privilege scope among all_trips ,request or request_receipt

Comment: @KyleDavis even in sandbox mode,I am getting 403 forbidden error.Is this API available in sandbox mode or not?

Comment: Secondly this API requires server_token and according to uber scope guide,scopes grant permission during OAuth.

Comment: The API is not available on sandbox either. And yes you are correct about scopes, we would need to whitelist your app (the overall server_token). If you are still interested in the reminders API please DM. Thanks.

Comment: how can I reach out through developer dashboard.I mean for which specific scope I should request access ? or DM @uberdevelopers is only way to request access